# Limiting :association results accessible on a form in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a very basic e-commerce app to teach myself rails and I've hit my first snag:

I created some associations so that merchants could assign categories to products they post and that works fine the way I've done it, however, the way it works now, when a merchant is creating a new product all the categories from the categories table are available to select.  Hypothetically, if I wanted to limit that list to only categories that that specific merchant has created or been associated with, I presume taken from the `categories_merchants` table, how would I go about doing that?

I've shown the relevant tables and a form below to show what I've done but left out the models, however I have all the appropriate associations in them:

Products Table:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.integer :merchant_id
  t.string :title
  t.text :body
  t.date :publish_date
  t.date :expiry_date
  t.timestamps
```

Categories Table:

```
create_table :categories do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
```

Categories_Products Table:

```
create_table :categories_products, :id =>false do |t|
  t.integer :category_id
  t.integer :product_id
end
add_index :categories_products, [:category_id, :product_id]
```

Categories_Merchants Table:

```
create_table :categories_merchants, :id =>false do |t|
  t.integer :category_id
  t.integer :merchant_id
end
add_index :categories_merchants, [:category_id, :merchant_id]
```

New Products form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.association :categories, :as => :collection_select %>
    <%= f.input :publish_date %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<%= f.association :categories, 
                  :as => :collection_select, 
                  :collection => Category.includes(:categories_merchants).where("categories_merchants.merchant_id = ?", merchant_id) %>
```